# Exception while deploying the app : Invalid URL Pattern: [{0}]

Tags: jsp, jsf, servlets

I am new to Java EE and am trying to develop a JavaServer Faces web application in Netbeans following chapter 7 of the tutorial- http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaServerFaces/article.html but I get the `Invalid URL Pattern` when I deploy it on glassfish as:

```
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [list2] : Invalid URL Pattern: [{0}]
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [list2]
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL Pattern: [{0}]
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.node.ServletMappingNode.setElementValue(ServletMappingNode.java:114)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.node.SaxParserHandler.endElement(SaxParserHandler.java:583)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:609)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:863)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1782)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2973)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:649)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:333)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:318)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.io.DeploymentDescriptorFile.read(DeploymentDescriptorFile.java:245)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readStandardDeploymentDescriptor(Archivist.java:665)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:391)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
    at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [list2] : Invalid URL Pattern: [{0}]
Info:   visiting unvisited references
Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [list2]
Severe:   Exception during lifecycle processing
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL Pattern: [{0}]
    at org.glassfish.web.deployment.node.ServletMappingNode.setElementValue(ServletMappingNode.java:114)
```

My web.xml file looks like-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
     id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>Todo.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

As seen, the `<welcome-file-list>` contains two `.jsp` files. The `index.jsp` is a simple Welcome file which gets deployed successfully when execute. The `index.jsp` file looks like-

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>To Do Welcome Page</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

And when I just write the `index.jsp` in the `<welcome-file-list>` of the `web.xml`, the application runs and gets deployed successfully but when I add the `Todo.jsp` file also in the `<welcome-file-list>`, I get the error mentioned above. My `Todo.jsp`looks like-

```
<%-- 
    Document   : Todo
    Created on : Jan 29, 2015, 2:19:46 PM
    Author     : shaifali
--%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
  pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<LINK href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/mystyle.css"
  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<h3>Todo list</h3>
<f:view>
  <h:messages layout="table"></h:messages>

  <%-- Possibility to start a new Todo --%>
  <h:form>
    <h:commandLink binding="#{todoController.addCommand}" accesskey="n"
      action="#{todoController.addNew}" value="Add new Todo">
    </h:commandLink>
  </h:form>


  <h:form binding="#{todoController.form}" rendered="false"
    styleClass="todo">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
      <h:outputText value="Title"></h:outputText>
      <h:inputText value="#{todoController.todo.title}" required="true"
        requiredMessage="Title is required">
      </h:inputText>
      <h:outputText value="Description"></h:outputText>
      <h:inputTextarea value="#{todoController.todo.description}" cols="40"
        rows="4"></h:inputTextarea>
      <h:outputText value="Prio"></h:outputText>
      <h:selectOneMenu validatorMessage="required"
        value="#{todoController.todo.priority}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{todoController.priorities}" />
      </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>
    <h:panelGroup>
      <h:commandButton action="#{todoController.save}" value="Save"
        accesskey="s">
      </h:commandButton>
      <h:commandButton action="#{todoController.cancel}" value="Cancel"
        accesskey="c" immediate="true">
      </h:commandButton>
    </h:panelGroup>
  </h:form>

  <%-- These buttons allow to show and hide the table --%>
  <h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
      <h:commandLink id="hide"
        actionListener="#{todoController.displayTable}" value="Hide Table">
      </h:commandLink>
      <h:commandLink id="show"
        actionListener="#{todoController.displayTable}" value="Show Table">
      </h:commandLink>
    </h:panelGrid>
  </h:form>

  <%-- Here we start the form for the data table --%>
  <h:form binding="#{todoController.tableForm}">
    <%-- Here we start the data table --%>

    <h:dataTable value="#{todoController.todos}" var="todo"
      styleClass="todo" headerClass="todoheader"
      columnClasses="first, rest">
      <h:column>
        <%-- Via this facet we define the table header (column 1) --%>
        <f:facet name="header">
          <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="Prio"></h:outputText>
          </h:column>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{todo.priority}"></h:outputText>
      </h:column>
      <h:column>
        <%-- Via this facet we define the table header (column 2) --%>
        <f:facet name="header">
          <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="Title"></h:outputText>
          </h:column>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{todo.title}"></h:outputText>

      </h:column>

      <h:column>
        <%-- Via this facet we define the table header (column 3) --%>
        <f:facet name="header">
          <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="Description"></h:outputText>
          </h:column>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{todo.description}"></h:outputText>
      </h:column>

      <h:column>
        <%-- Via this facet we define the table header (column 4) --%>
        <f:facet name="header">
          <h:column>
            <h:outputText value="Actions"></h:outputText>
          </h:column>
        </f:facet>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
          <h:commandLink value="delete" action="#{todoController.delete}">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{todoController.todo}"
              value="#{todo}" />
          </h:commandLink>
        </h:panelGrid>
      </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>

  </h:form>
</f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

I am unable to resolve the error. Any help with the same would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why did you map `FacesServlet` twice? Instead, you could mention valid URL patterns (`<url-pattern>`) more than once inside the same `<servlet-mapping>` XML element.

Comment: The tutorial you linked to is targeted to JSF 1.2. Seek for the latest tutorials unless you have to stick to JSF 1.2 for some unclear reasons.

Comment: I adjusted the `<servlet-mapping>` and added the `jsf-api-1.2.jar`. It works now.